# "Line Intersections" tool does not create point where lines intersect

Tags: qgis, line, qgis-processing, intersection

When I use the "Line Intersections" tool in QGIS, it doesn't create whole intersect points. Also, the gif and picture below show that the lines intersect but the plugin doesn't assign any point to them. How can I solve the problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The geometries, you think they are two separate lines, may be one polyline. If it is, the tool doesn't generate intersection points for the lines within the same geometry, even if it contains an intersection.

Comment: Select the line(s), if it is one geometry, then you should split it and run the tool again. Otherwise,  the lines probably do not touch.

Comment: This line, which is inside the circle is not the polyline.  Also, when we use the v.clean tool in QGIS, the same situation happened and there is no problem with snapping.

Comment: If they dont touch, take a look at "Extend lines" or "Snap geometries to layer" from processing toolbox.

Comment: Did you run the check validity tool by any chance?  I always do if a tool fails to work as expected since it is quick and easy.

Comment: The "Extend lines" tool generates a new layer but when I use the line intersection tool with this layer the result same. The "Snap geometries to layer" tool generates some lines that I don' want nevertheless I used the line intersection tool with this layer also it doesn't generate necessary points.

Comment: I ran the check validity tool. There were 4 intersections with no point generated. There were 3 intersections after using this tool. But it doesn't generate for all intersections.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/69539559/820534

Comment: Another possibility is described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263103/creating-vertex-where-two-lines-meet-using-qgis/263140#263140): use v.clean [Grass]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very common issue in GIS. In the case of your data, it occurs because the vertical line doesn't have a node that matches the final point of the diagonal line, and due to [geometric non-robustness](https://www.crunchydata.com/videos/postgis-spatial-overlay/), the geometry engine fails finding an intersection there.

**Solution**

You need to make sure the layer has a proper topology before running the `Line intersections` algorithm (it means, either modify your original layer or run the `Line intersections` over a modified copy of your original layer). In practice, just follow these steps:

1. Run the [`Snap Geometries to Layer`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#snap-geometries-to-layer) with the following parameters:

   [image]

   Same `input` and `reference` layers. The `tolerance` is up to you, but a tolerance of 1 mm. works well for most cases (planar coordinates). Regarding the `behavior`, you can choose the second option, called `Prefer closest point, insert extra vertices where required` (it's important to choose one that inserts vertices).
2. Run the [`Line intersections`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#line-intersections) algorithm using the output of the step 1.

And that's it. Doing that you'll get the point intersections you expect.

[image]

---

**Tip**

I suggest you to build a model like the following, so that you get what you want in one go. Anyway, you'll probably need to remove the duplicated intersections the `Line intersections` returns.

[image]

---

*Note 1: The `Snap Geometries to Layer` algorithm has been heavily optimized and adjusted lately (see https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/42781 and https://twitter.com/GeoTux2/status/1435136250487480320). So, you need to use QGIS >= v3.21.x. QGIS 3.22.0 will be released in 9 days, but you can download a nightly build if you cannot wait until then.*

*Note 2: Fortunately, GEOS v3.9 solves this issue of geometric non-robustness. Therefore, as soon as QGIS upgrades GEOS to v3.9, we'll be able to see the expected results without intermediate steps (like running `Snap Geometries to Layer`). Since these thing don't happen automatically, you could get involved in the project. Sometimes an effort from the community itself is needed before such changes happen (e.g., via funding).*

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the robustness aspect? Basically, it is due to a rounding issue that snapping does not always work as expected, is that correct?

Comment: I tried your solution with the dataset provided by OP. I used the very settings you propose for the 'Snap Geometries to Layer' tool, however, line intersection on the modified layer still doesn't find all intersecting points. I increased tolerance to 1 m, still with the same result. Using QGIS 3.20.0 with GEOS 3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.2. Using the extend line solution works with OP's (unprocessed) dataset, even the simple intersection operation with QGIS expression works, without extending the lines.

Comment: @Babel, the answer says that you need to use at least QGIS 3.21 (dev version). Yes, that's also something I explained in the answer, GEOS 3.9 solves the issue, see Note 2.

Answer (score 4):

Probably in the cases where you don't get an intersection, probably the lines do not touch or there is a [snapping issue like this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/379655/88814). There's probably a (very tiny) gap- so small you don't see it. The solution is to make the lines a tiny bit longer: to extend it using QGIS expression [extend](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#extend).

You can test it by applying an additional [Geometry generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-geometry-generator) symbol layer, rendering as point and using this expression:

```
intersection(
    $geometry,  
    difference(
        collect($geometry),
        $geometry
        )
    )
```

Than change this expression by replacing `$geometry` in line two by this: `extend ($geometry, 0.1, 0.1)`. With this, you make your lines a tiny bit longer (by `0.1` map units - change this value if needed). In this case, you get additional intersection points where the initial lines do not touch.
When satisfied with the result, you can convert it to actual geometries (new layer) using [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) with the same expression. Run [Multipart to single parts](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts) on the result.

*Left: one line does not intersect the others (red circle); Right: with the revised expression, you also get a point there:*
[image]

Comment: I used the snapping tool and also I checked the intersection without point there is no problem with snapping. I zoomed enough. I applied your solution. It generates some points but also line intersection tool generates them. Your solution does not generate any point that. line intersection tool does not generate too.

Comment: Can you share your data (or a sample of it), containing the problematic spots?

Comment: https://github.com/aycatbkoglu/QGIS-Intersection-tool-error-dataset our dataset is in the repo

Comment: I downloaded your files and applied the first expression from my answer (without extend_line): all intersections show correctly, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjnue.png - did you try this solution? It should return all intersection points correctly

Comment: Line intersection tool indeed does not generate all points, even if they seem to be snapped. However, QGIS seems to have a snapping problem sometimes, see this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/379655/88814 . The solution here is to extend the lines a little bit: with that, even the Line interesection tool creates all correct points.